# Real-time update of values inside a call_back function[the values are from external function(of another .m file)]

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have an external function say "external_func" (seperate .m file)

Inside this function a while loop is called, and this while loop update a variabl named "update_prog"

Now I will pass this value into the GUIDE using

```
assignin('base', 'update_prog', update_prog); % passing to workspace
```

I am making this

"update_prog" as global variable and calling it into GUIDE .m file

```
function pb1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global update_prog

% hObject    handle to pb1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% else
%      set(handles.pb1,'enable','on');
% end
% update_prog first value prints, but it wont updates as the loop in external_func goes on.
drawnow;
set(handles.slider1,'Value',update_prog)
 external_func;
```

so here in the GUIDE .m file I can get the value

"update_prog" but it wont keep up with the while loop. I used "drawnow" but its of no use.

How can I refine this value "update_prog" as the while loop in the "external_func" goes through multiple iterations. [Note: The updated values are there in the callback function of GUIDE, but unless there is a callback the callback function wont update the "update_prog"], so how can I acheive this real-time update inside a call_back function.

[Note: passing the variables through function input is not possible here in my case, so I am looking for alternatives]

Edit1: please consider this link, which has an example[Which may clarify you what I am trying to acheive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421213/make-the-slider-as-a-progress-bar-in-matlab-guide)

What I am doing here is

1. Passing the variable(which is being updated in the while loop of the externel function) into GUI.
2. I will use this variable to show the progress on the progress bar(Slider).

What is the problem? 
 1. The variable inside the GUI callback(Consdier I will press a push button and then it will call the function with while loop) will put the updated values into the `set(handles.slider,'Value',variable)`

By doing this I cant move the slider.

Why?

1. Callback updates the variable only when I press the push button, next all the updates to the variable will not be updated, so progress bar/slider wont move.

Comment: Do you want to update the slider fully automatic?

Comment: @matlabgui...yeah I am trying to update it automatically as per the changes to the variable in while loop. (Pushbutton just starts the main_func, apart from that it has no more importance).

Comment: You state you cannot pass vars - but can you modify the `external_func`?

Comment: Modifying external_func is not at all possible in my case. So I am trying to change the values for slider inside the GUI (After successfully passing the updated values of variable to GUI)

Comment: if you cannot modify -> how can you pass the updated value?

Comment: @matlabgui I have made the variable as global. So every time a change happens to the variable, it will be reflected in the GUI(I have checked this). The only problem is I have to force the slider to take these updated values.(The push button calls the main_func and main_func updates the variable values. so I am doing set(handles.slider,'Value',variable) inside the push button)

Comment: so you can modify (1 or 2 lines) in `external_func`  - not the inputs

Comment: @matlabgui  yeah ofcourse I can add or modify one or two lines/ few lines for that matter. (Sorry, before I thought you meant to change the structure of the main_func).

Comment: Now I have seen your previous question around the same slider update (I think) I understand your objective better. It is not good practice to **push** update of a gui control (like your slider) from an external program/function. It can cause all sorts of timing issues and its more performance intensive. It is better that the gui itself **pulls** any value it requires from an accessible part of memory, but on its own timing.

Comment: So I would recommend you to choose whichever memory transfer method you prefer (`assignin`, `global` or `set/getappdata`) but I think you should really use a `timer` method (like in my example) to make sure the gui queries the values only when it's ready.

Comment: @Hoki...Thnaks for all the suggessions...I will work on that tomorrow, I will let you know about the outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to pass your variable in 3 steps with an intermediate workspace (external->base workspace->GUI). I would rather recommend to pass your variable directly (external->GUI).

Each Matlab figure offers a space to store variables (Application Data) of any type. I would suggest reading the article [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) and read the documentation for the 3 functions:

- [guidata](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)
- [setappdata](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)
- [getappdata](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html)

This way will offer you much more control over the scope of your variables and you won't need any `global` declaration.

---

Below is an example of a simple gui. The gui declare the variable in it's user space (with `setappdata`), then uses a timer to periodically read this variable (with `getappdata`).
The external function do whatever you want it to do (just a random number in the example), then to update the variable you use the same `setappdata`. The only thing you need for that is the handle of the main GUI figure, so in the example I give it as input of the external function.

The GUI also has two buttons to start and stop the update.

[image]

---

The code for the main example GUI 'theGui.m' is :

```
function h = theGui

%// basic GUI with 2 buttons and 1 slider
h.fig = figure('Position',[433 434 500 100],'Menubar','none','CloseRequestFcn',@my_closefcn) ;
h.sld = uicontrol('Style','Slider','Position',[20 20 460 20]) ;
h.btnStart = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Start updating','Callback',@btnStart_callback,'Position',[20 50 200 30]);
h.btnStop  = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Stop updating','Callback',@btnStop_callback,'Position',[280 50 200 30],'Max',1,'Min',0);

%// Define the timer
h.t = timer ;
h.t.Period = 0.1 ; %// 0.1s refresh interval
h.t.TimerFcn = {@timer_callback,h.fig} ;
h.t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedSpacing' ;

%// initialise the variable to update in the GUI appdata
update_prog = 0 ;
setappdata( h.fig , 'update_prog' , update_prog ) ;

%// save handles
guidata( h.fig , h );


function btnStart_callback(hobj,~)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;           %// retrieve handles
    if strcmp('off',h.t.Running)    %// Start timer (only if not already running)
        start(h.t)
    end

function btnStop_callback(hobj,~)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;   %// retrieve handles
    stop(h.t)               %// Stop timer

function timer_callback(~,~,hfig)
    update_prog = getappdata( hfig , 'update_prog' ) ;  %// retrieve the 'update_prog' variable value
    h = guidata( hfig ) ;                               %// retrieve handles
    set(h.sld , 'Value' , update_prog) ;                %// update the slider object with the retrieved value

function my_closefcn(hobj,~)
%// this function is only to clean up when the GUI will be closed.
%// It is recommended to delete the timer manually
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;   %// retrieve handles
    stop(h.t)               %// Stop timer (in case it is still running)
    delete(h.t) ;           %// delete the timer
    delete(h.fig) ;         %// destroy the figure
```

And the code for `external_func.m`

```
function external_func( guiMainFigureHandle )
%// This function will only generate random numbers and push them into the
%// variable 'update_prog' contained in the GUI appdata.
%// This is why this function NEEDS the handle of the gui to be able to
%// access the Application Data space of the gui.

for k = 1:100
    randomValue = rand(1) ;                              %// generate a random value
    hfig = ancestor( guiMainFigureHandle , 'figure' ) ;  %// make sure the handle provided is the top level figure
    setappdata( hfig , 'update_prog' , randomValue) ;    %// update the variable value
    pause(0.1) ;
end
```

---

Edit:
I place this in edit instead of changing the code above because I don't recommend messing with the `root` object if you don't need to. But in your case it can be a way round your problem.

If your external function doesn't have access to the GUI, it can always update a part of memory which is available for **all** the programs running in a given Matlab session, namely the `root` object. The handle for it is reserved and is the same for any program: `0` (although since v2014b there is another way to invoke it : [groot](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html), it is still always the same handle for all Matlab).

So in the example above, in `theGui.m`, use instead:

```
setappdata( 0 , 'update_prog' , update_prog ) ;
```

in the main routine, then in the subfunction `function timer_callback(~,~,hfig)`, use:

```
update_prog = getappdata( 0 , 'update_prog' ) ;  %// retrieve the 'update_prog' variable
```

And your function `external_func()` doesn't need any extra argument, the update only needs one line:

```
setappdata( 0 , 'update_prog' , update_prog) ;    %// update the variable value
```

Comment: consider I cant pass the figure handle to the extgernal_func as an input, like what this line is doing.....function external_func( guiMainFigureHandle )....your solution wont work then.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner. Well, since you have access to the code of `external_func` I am not sure why you cannot pass an extra variable to it ?? Anyway, in extreme cases (like the one you describe) where you do not have access to the handle of the main gui, you can also use the root Matlab application (identified by the handle `0`) to store your variable. So just replace everywhere `hfig` by `0` in the set/getappdata lines. (like that : `setappdata( 0, 'update_prog' , update_prog);`, and the same for the `getappdata` lines. This way you do not need any input to `external_func`.

Answer (score 0):

I "suspect" that your `update_prog` variable in the base workspace is not a global (you must define it to be global in every workspace that you want to use it).

Since your using globals (there are many better ways to do this - but thats not your question) - why don't you simply define the `update_prog` variable to be global in your `external_func` function (replace the assign call).

**edit**  put a drawnow in your `external_func` function.  That way when you click on the button it will update.

**edit 3**

I think I know what you want to do, try this example and see if it does what you want - updated to show how you find the slider object in your code and update inside your loop:

```
function  mygui
  % create a figure
  f = figure;
  % create a uicontrol slider - note that I give it a tag.
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'slider', 'Position', [0 200 200 40], 'tag', 'MYSLIDER', 'backgroundcolor', 'white', 'parent', f );
  % create a push button which we can press to update
  uicontrol ( 'string', 'Press 2 start', 'callback', @(a,b)myLoop(), 'Position', [0 0 200 50] )
end

% This replicates your "external_func" function.
function myLoop()
  % since you cant pass in any var -> you need to find the slider object
  % you can do this by using findobj and search for the tag of the item
  uic = findobj ( 0, 'tag', 'MYSLIDER' );
  % find the figure handle (only needed for this demo)
  f = ancestor ( uic, 'figure' ); 
  % initialise the value which will be used to update the slider
  count = 0;
  % create your loop
  while ishandle(f)
    % incrememt the count variable -> this will end up on the slider value
    count = count + 1e-5;
    % reset count if > 1 -> so the slider cant go out of range.
    if count >= 1
      count = 0;
    end
    set ( uic, 'Value', count );
    % initiate a drawnow -> this allows matlab to process GUI events
    drawnow();
  end
end
```

The downside of this is you insert a drawnow in your loop -> which could slow it down somewhat.

If this doesn't fix your problem you need to explain better what you want to do... (in my view)

Comment: What he would need would be co-routines, but one cannot implement those in MATLAB. The idea that there is a callback that interrupts an already executing function, and the callback makes a change in a shared variable so the change will affect the next iteration in the interrupted function when the callback returns.

Comment: @matlabgui that was redundant. I removed assignin. Thanks. But nothing changes though, everything remains same. [workspace assignment was one extra thing that was going on]. It doesnt really make any changes to the behaviour.

Comment: @CST-Link ...yes that is exactly what is going on. I could see the values updating once the callback is done. I could see the progress of the values inside callback if I just break the loop(just to check).

Comment: @statisticalbeginner I believe that we had this discussion already: you mustn't launch your external function from the GUI, because you'll have no way to interrupt it with callbacks (the callback will either be discarded, or will wait for the function to finish). The GUI and the external function can be, however, launched from the same script or function.

Comment: @matlabgui ...I think you misunderstood my question. let me clarify what I am doing here. I am able to update the values for "update_prog" inside the push_button callback funtion(as I told in my question, "upate_prog" is a variable from the external_func). and this pushbutton call_back function then has to update the slider's value handle(as you can see I am setting the handle of slider to a new update_prog value), so that when the main function is in progress, then slider can move to show the progress. [Problem: slider handle wont update as per the update_prog value]

Comment: @CST-Link...thanks for the suggestion. If I could change the order of the project tree/file tree , I would hav changed it by now. But the actual structure is like, a script is doing something and then it calls a function, which internally calls another external function, which calls another and after 4 files, I end up in the file with the while loop(the one with the actual calculation). So thats the reason I am still trying to acheive it somehow withrough changing the project tree/file tree.

Comment: @matlabgui ... I have edited my question, where I have explained it with an example.

Comment: I did use your suggestion, and it gives me this warning and and does nothing to the slider movement. ???  The warning is like......Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double".
 See MATLAB 7.0.4 Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning for details.                                                     So It uic.Value inside the function is not belongs to the slider instead the loop is creating a new structure for uic. [Note: As I told in my question my external_func is not in gui's .m file, but its in seperate .m file]. Thanks

Comment: Updated setting the slider value command to work with numeric handles `set ( uic, 'value', count )`